# Download excel file using memory stream in C#

Tags: c#, interop, excel-interop, closedxml, spire.xls

I have to return file by creating excel workbook from memory stream. I have used Interop, closed.xml, spire.xls but not founding a way to achieve the same.

```
    var stream=clsUploadHelper.GetAttachmentFileStream(string.Empty, Filename);
Workbook book=new Workbook();
book.worksheet.Add(stream);
                            stream.Position = 0;
                            string xmlString = "attachment;filename=" + Filename;
                            return File(stream, xmlString, Filename);
```

I am new in that, Please help if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jazb Actually already byte written to the file that are coming for the download and using that byte/stream we just need to return an excel file

Comment: @all anyone please help

Comment: Tell us what framework you're using. You didn't specify, but it looks like you're building a Web UI.

Answer (score 0):

may be late to the party, but I ran into this issue today and was able to write this POC in order to return an XLSX file in a .NET Core Web API using Spire.XLS

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<FileResult> Post()
    {
        try
        {

            var workbook = new Workbook();
            var sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

            sheet.InsertRow(1);
            sheet.Rows[0].Columns[0].Value = "testing...";

            await using var stream = new MemoryStream();
            workbook.SaveToStream(stream, Spire.Xls.FileFormat.Version2016);

            const string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            HttpContext.Response.ContentType = contentType;
            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");

            var fileContentResult = new FileContentResult(stream.ToArray(), contentType)
            {
                FileDownloadName = $"test.xlsx"
            };

            return fileContentResult;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```